# Remote SharedObject isn't synced/persisted

Tags: shared-objects, flash-media-server

I'm using FMS 4.0. I'm trying to use the Remote SharedObject, which I've I used in the past, but nothing seems to work. Even the most simple example doesn't work. No events are triggered on the SO instance (no NetStatusEvent or SyncEvent). No exceptions, no nothing.

```
import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.net.SharedObject;
import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
import flash.events.AsyncErrorEvent;
import flash.events.SyncEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
var so:SharedObject;
var url:String = "rtmp://127.0.0.1/live";
var tm:Timer = new Timer(1000);

nc.client = {};

nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, function(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
  trace("nc netstatus event", event.info.code);

  if (event.info.code !== "NetConnection.Connect.Success") {
    return;
  }

  so = SharedObject.getRemote("settings", nc.uri, true);
  so.client = {};
  so.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, trace);

  so.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, function(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
    trace("so netstatus event", event.info.code);
  });

  so.addEventListener(SyncEvent.SYNC, function(event:SyncEvent):void {
    trace("so synced");
    trace("time", so.data.time);
  });

  so.connect(nc);
  tm.start();
});

tm.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, function(event:TimerEvent):void {
  trace("tick");
  so.setProperty("time", new Date().toString());
});

nc.connect(url);
```

I'm using the Developer license, so SharedObjects should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your rtmp address is: rtmp://127.0.0.1/live
Isn't that a connection to localhost? I think you are supposed to use 
rtmp:/127.0.0.1/live 
when you connect to localhost instead of an internet ip address (i.e. use just one slash)